# How does the front-end of a core on Xeon Phi allocate instructions for its U-pipe and V-pipe?

Tags: cpu, intel, pipeline, xeon-phi

According to several Intel documents, I understand that a core on Xeon Phi can issue up to 2 instructions per cycle. One on U-pipe and one on V-pipe. The following documentation states that the the front-end switches among multiple contexts in a round-robin fashion. **Are these 2 instructions coming from the same context? Or, can they come from different contexts?** I don't think they can, but I haven't find detailed documentations on this.

> Another important thing to know about the front-end of the Intel Xeon
> Phi coprocessor pipeline is that it does not issue instructions from
> the same hardware context (hardware thread) for two clock cycles in a
> row, even if that hardware context is the only one executing. So, in
> order to achieve the maximum issue rate, at least two hardware
> contexts must be running. With multiple contexts running, the
> front-end will switch between them in a round-robin fashion.

Source: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimization-and-performance-tuning-for-intel-xeon-phi-coprocessors-part-2-understanding

Also, assuming we have a vector instruction and a scalar instruction, **does the front-end issue the vector one in the U-pipe and the scalar one in the V-pipe to achieve the maximum issue rate?** I wonder because the actual use of these two pipelines influences the issue rate given that the V-pipe can only execute a small subset of vector instructions.

> The core is a 2-wide processor meaning it can execute two instructions
> per cycle, one on U-pipe and the other on V-pipe. It also contains an
> x87 unit to perform floating point instructions when needed.
>
> ...
>
> The vector unit communicates with the core and executes vector
> instructions allocated in the U or V pipeline. The core can execute
> two instructions per clock, one on U-pipe and another on the V-pipe.
> The V-pipe executes a subset of the instructions and is governed by
> instruction pairing rules, which is important to account for in
> getting optimum processor performance.

Source: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-xeon-phi-core-micro-architecture

Answer (score 1):

The processor will simultaneously issue to the U and V pipes on the **same** hardware context.

It is only able to do this if there are suitable U and V pipe instructions on the instruction stream associated with that hardware context.

Because KNC is in order, quite often only one pipe can be utilised per issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about scalar instructions? Assuming we have 4 contexts with independent scalar instructions, can 2 issues per cycle be achieved?